# Flutter problem when add provider and doesnot response that

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

question:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => CounterCubit(CounterCubit.get(context).state),
      child: BlocConsumer(
        listener: (context, state){
            if(CounterStates is plusState){
              print("plusState");
          }
            if(CounterStates is minusState){
              print("minusState");
            }
          } ,
        builder: (context, state) {
          return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(),
            body: Center(
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      CounterCubit.get(context).counter++;
                    },
                    icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                    iconSize: 50,
                    color: Colors.amber,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 20,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "${CounterCubit.get(context).counter}",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 100,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                      color: Colors.black,
      
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 20,
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      CounterCubit.get(context).counter--;
                    },
                    icon: Icon(Icons.remove),
                    iconSize: 50,
                    color: Colors.amber,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

======================================================================================================
problem:
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following ProviderNotFoundException was thrown building _InheritedProviderScope<CounterCubit?>(value: <not yet loaded>):
Error: Could not find the correct Provider<StateStreamable<Object?>> above this BlocConsumer<StateStreamable<Object?>, Object?> Widget

This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:

- You added a new provider in your `main.dart` and performed a hot-reload.
  To fix, perform a hot-restart.
- The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.

  Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route, then
  other routes will not be able to access that provider.
- You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.

  Make sure that BlocConsumer<StateStreamable<Object?>, Object?> is under your MultiProvider/Provider<StateStreamable<Object?>>.
  This usually happens when you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediately.

  For example, instead of:

  ```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // Will throw a ProviderNotFoundError, because `context` is associated
      // to the widget that is the parent of `Provider<Example>`
      child: Text(context.watch<Example>().toString()),
    );
  }
  ```

  consider using `builder` like so:

  ```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // we use `builder` to obtain a new `BuildContext` that has access to the provider
      builder: (context, child) {
        // No longer throws
        return Text(context.watch<Example>().toString());
      }
    );
  }
  ```

increase and decrease number